# Suppress shell opened by subprocess in python (.pyw) script

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a subprocess launched by Popen which runs a shell command and opens an .exe file like this:

```
subprocess.Popen("cscs.exe" + <some params>, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The output of this process is being redirected to a gui element, which is why i want to hide the shell as it doesn't display anything anyway.

The `shell=False` option doesn't do anything.
When i launch my script as a .py file, only the python.exe shell opens and nothing else. As soon as i changed it to .pyw the shell for cscs.exe started popping up.

How do i suppress this cscs.exe shell?